# Writting a join query for following four tables to get records if a certain condition meets

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, relational-database, greatest-n-per-group

[image]

From top to bottom WorkOrderID has many JobIDs, each JobID has some StatusID.
i want to get only those record for WorkOrderIDs whose each JobID has StatusID == 9.

According to the data given in tables i want to fetch only one result row which is for WorkOrderID 6, because all jobs(JobID ==1 and 2) under WorkOrderID==6, have StatusID ==9.

JobID == 4, 5, 6, 7 belongs to WorkOrderID ==7 so not fetch record for WorkOrderID==7 because one of its JobID has StatusID other than 9 (JobID ==4 has StatusID==1), in the sense this WorkOrderID has not yet completed.

Let the names for the tables from top to bottom be. **WorkOrders**, **Jobs**, **Jobs_Status**, **Status**

Comment: Is it possible for a JobID to have no StatusID, or for it to have more than one StatusID?  There are various approaches, but knowing is this is possible *(And how you want to treat it)* is fundamental to your question.  *(For example, could JobID=1 have another StatusID for a different StatusTrackDate?  And if so, do you only want to take account of the most recent StatusTrackDate for each JobID?  Or could a JobID appear without a StatusID yet, and so be treated as not having a StatusID of 9?)*

Comment: i need to fetch only those records only if all JobIDs under some WorkOrderID have StatusID==9.

Comment: You didn't answer any of my questions about your data.

Comment: JobID could have atleast one Status ID and it can have more StatusIDs at different StatusTrackDate. and yes we can take account of the most recent StatusTackDate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give it a try

```
SELECT * FROM WorkOrders WHERE WorkOrderID IN (
SELECT WorkOrderID FROM Jobs WHERE jobID IN (
SELECT jobID FROM Jobs_Status WHERE StatusID =9))
```

One thing i want to clear the `jobID (1,2,5,6,7)` has the `StatusID =9` so the `WorkOrderID` against `jobID (1,2,5,6,7)` are **6,7** so on what basis your are saying

> According to the data given in tables we will have only one result row which is for WorkOrderID 6, because all jobs(JobID ==1 and 2) under WorkOrderID==6, have StatusID ==9

It will return both the results `WorkOrderID  6,7`

Now this will return the `WorkOrderID  6` as per your requirnment

```
SELECT q.* FROM  (
SELECT w.`WorkOrderID`,
(SELECT 
 GROUP_CONCAT(`jobID` SEPARATOR ',') FROM `jobs` WHERE  `jobs`.`WorkOrderID`=w.`WorkOrderID` GROUP BY `jobs`.`WorkOrderID`) AS Alljobids
 , GROUP_CONCAT(j.`jobID` SEPARATOR ',') AS onlystatusids
FROM `workorders` w INNER JOIN `jobs` j ON (w.`WorkOrderID` = j.`WorkOrderID`)
INNER JOIN `jobs_status` js ON (j.`jobID` = js.`jobID`) WHERE js.`StatusID`=9 

GROUP BY w.`WorkOrderID`) q WHERE  q.Alljobids=q.onlystatusids
```

Here is the another way using `HAVING`

```
SELECT w.`WorkOrderID`,
(SELECT 
 GROUP_CONCAT(`jobID` SEPARATOR ',') FROM `jobs` WHERE  `jobs`.`WorkOrderID`=w.`WorkOrderID` GROUP BY `jobs`.`WorkOrderID`) AS Alljobids
 , GROUP_CONCAT(j.`jobID` SEPARATOR ',') AS onlystatusids
FROM `workorders` w INNER JOIN `jobs` j ON (w.`WorkOrderID` = j.`WorkOrderID`)
INNER JOIN `jobs_status` js ON (j.`jobID` = js.`jobID`) WHERE js.`StatusID`=9 
GROUP BY w.`WorkOrderID`
HAVING Alljobids=onlystatusids
```

**Here is your [Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6f6ee/1) If you don't believe :)**

Comment: This is what i do not want to get both results. WorkOrderID==6 has two jobs (both have StatusID ==9, in the sense WorkOrderID==6 is completed) and should be printed and for WorkOrderID==7 one of its JobID which is JobID==4 has StatusID other than 9 (not completed yet) so should not be fetched.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to think about problems like this (in my opinion) is to layout your query in three parts:  a **SELECT** section that lists the columns you want, a **FROM** section that shows the tables needed and the JOIN conditions, and a **WHERE** section that is used to subset the data rows you need.

So from the description of your question, perhaps this will work:

```
SELECT WorkOrders.WorkOrderID

FROM WorkOrders
JOIN Jobs
ON   Jobs.WorkOrderID = WorkOrders.WorkOrderID
JOIN Jobs_Status
ON   Jobs_Status.JobID = Jobs.JobID
JOIN Status
ON   Status.StatusID = Jobs_Status.StatusID

WHERE Jobs_Status.StatusID = 9
```

Notice that I have included the JOIN condition to the table `Status` but I only did that for illustration.  Actually joining to that table is not necessary (the value from `Jobs_Status` is good enough.

Comment: This prints both rows (WorkOrderID 6, 7). i do not want to fetch WorkOrderID 7 because one of its JoIDs has StatusID==1 (JobID, 4).